# Delete elasticsearch template in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, elasticsearch

I am trying to delete elasticsearch template in Windows, however, it keeps giving me error result like this.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/ 
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'XGET'. 
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/
+      ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand



PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\curator> curl GET localhost:9200/_template/
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'localhost:9200/_template/'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl GET localhost:9200/_template/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Is there anyway to resolve the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` is an alias for the [Invoke-WebRequest](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217035) cmdlet:

```
get-command curl | select Name

Name
----
curl
```

`-XGET` is equivalent to `-Method Get` which is the default. So this should work:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'http://localhost:9200/_template/'
```

Note: You probably have to adopt the scheme.

Comment: Then how can I completely remove a template and index

Comment: I don't know the elasticsearch API, probably you have to use the `Delete` verb on the `-Method` parameter.

Comment: I have accidentally found that the google chrome extension plugin 'postman' did a great work to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I use postman too for rest invokes. You can also save your methods invokes in a collection ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is a great tool. Thanks